# Create silent notification

Tags: android, android-studio

I have function that creates notification. Each time it formats notification it play sound. Is it possible to create silent notification that not plays sound? How to achieve that?

```
public void sendNotification(String title, String message,boolean playSound) {


        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 234;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            CharSequence name = "my_channel";
            String Description = "This is my channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(Description);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message);


        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        builder.setContentIntent(intent);



        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Except using

```
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
```

use

```
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
```

You need to use PRIORITY_LOW for devices below Android 7 and use IMPORTANCE_LOW for Android 8 and above.

Also you can use setSound(null, null) method on your NotificationChannel(mChannel)

Comment: Also take into account that you can not modify a notificationChannel once created (except unistalling the app). So maybe considere having two notifications channels a silent and a sound one